# R formula to find rows which contains non case-sensitive text

Tags: r

Can someone help me revise my existing formula to look for rows in FileA based on row value in fileB, which should be non case-sensitive. I have this formula for now:
For (num in 1:nrow(dic)){

```
row1=which(FileA$'Position' == FileB$'Position)'[num])
row2=which(FileA$'Job Title' ==FileB$'Job Title'[num])
row= intersect (row1, row2)
```

So the result should return me all the rows found in FileA based on the content of row in FileB, non case sensitive.

Comment: Read about merge: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right

Comment: I am looking for formula not for joining but for capturing the rows non case-sensitive based on the content of the row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
v1 <- c("Horse","Cat","Dog")
v2 <- c("Bird","horse","giraffe","dog")
intersect(tolower(v1),tolower(v2))
#[1] "horse" "dog"
```

Comment: Yeah! This totally makes sense. Will also use grep if in case. Thanks!